# C# Google Drive SDK example app does not upload a file

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I've set up my sample application by using the documentation here https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs but at the end of the sample code

```
File file = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

the `request.ResponseBody;` is null. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose was, in Google apis, in API Project -> Services I had only Drive SDK turned ON, but also the Drive API must be turned ON